# Why when $-(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_T\geq 0$ we can say $-\frac{1}{V}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_T\geq 0$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Why when $-(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_T\geq 0$ we can say $-\frac{1}{V}(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p})_T\geq 0$ where V is the volume, p is the mean pressure of the system under consideration and T is the temperature which is kept fixed? Or why $\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}$ is the reciprocal of $\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}$? I think in calculus there is no such theorem or statement, but in Reif's statistical mechanics I find such a statement and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume a function $f{\left(x\right)}$ is invertible, e.g. by assuming that it is monotonic.  Let its inverse be called, suggestively, $X{\left(F\right)}$. We have

$$X{\left(f{\left(x\right)}\right)} = x,$$

and now differentiate both sides and use the chain rule to get

$$\left.\frac{dX}{dF}\right|_{F=f{\left(x\right)}} \frac{df}{dx} = 1.$$

Identifying $P{\left(V\right)}$ with the inverse function of $V{\left(P\right)}$ thus allows us to obtain the relation you desire.

We don't really need to assume the function is globally invertible. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem